# What is wrong with my pom file causing this build error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have reinstalled Java and reset JAVA_HOME to make sure maven is using the correct Java version but I am continuing to receive this error:

> #9 67.23 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:repackage (repackage) on project backend: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:repackage failed: Unable to load the mojo 'repackage' in the plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/springframework/boot/maven/RepackageMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 60.0

I'm currently getting this output:

> zack project-portfolio >> java --version
> openjdk 19.0.1 2022-10-18
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 19.0.1)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 19.0.1, mixed mode, sharing)
> zack project-portfolio >> mvn --v
> Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
> Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec
> Java version: 19.0.1, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/19.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
> OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.0.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac".

What could be wrong with the following pom.xml file as I feel it is a dependency issue? Or could it be an issue with my `Dockerfile`?

*`pom.xml`*

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>Backend for portfolio</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Java version set in `pom.xml` is `1.7`. Try with `17` or even `19`.

Comment: @MartinBG that doesn't change anything

Comment: It should. The issue is you're running maven using Java 19, but Maven compiles the project using Java 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Java 17 is the minimum requirement for spring boot 3.x version. Refer this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0) for more information. Set the Java environment to JDK17 to resolve the error.

References
https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/

Comment: Shouldn't JDK19 work which is what I am using?

Answer (score 0):

You need Java 17 to run spring boot 3.

Comment: I think I am using Java 19 and don't think that would be the issue

Comment: Try to see if Language level is set >17 in File ->Project Structure -> Project @MartinBG